# What's wrong with my Twitter Bootstrap's Row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to troubleshoot a problem with my Bootstrap page via previous questions on here, Google, and Bootstrap's documentation, but in the past two days I've been unable to solve the problem. Sadly, I bet it's something pretty simple.

I modded the size of the hero-unit and added a background image to it. Since then, the div row underneath it has been breaking up into three separate lines rather than maintaining the three span4's on a single line. Again, I'm sure this is a stupid question, but I am still fairly new to Bootstrap and how the grids work.

Anyone know what the problem is and how to correct it? Code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>With Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ascentapps.com/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt|Dosis:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

 <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

         <div class="hero-unit">
         </br>
         </br>
         </br>
         </br>
         </br>
         </br>
         </br>
         <div align="center">
         <h1><center>Moving Sale?</center></color></h1>
         </br>
         <p style= "color: white; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; font-size: 22px">Make it a whole lot easier</p>
         </div>
         </div><!-- .hero-unit -->

         <div class="row">
         <div class="span4">
         <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span>
         </button>
         <p>text</p></center>
         </div><!-- .span4 -->

         <div class="span4">
         <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
         </button>
         <p>text </p></center>
         </div><!-- .span4 -->

         <div class="span4">
         <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
         </button>
         <p>text </p></center>
         </div><!-- .span4 -->

 </div><!-- .row -->
 </div><!-- .container -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS I've added on to the end of the standard bootstrap.min.css:

```
.hero-unit {height: 100%; max-height:400px; min-height:400px;background:url(http://ascentapps.com/furniture.jpg)}h1 {font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;color:white;}span.glyphicon-paperclip {border: 3px solid orange;color: orange;font-size: 8em;}span.glyphicon-pushpin {border: 3px solid orange;color: orange;font-size: 8em;}span.glyphicon-lock {border: 3px solid orange;color: orange;font-size: 8em;}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

.glyphicon-bell:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-bookmark:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-briefcase:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-calendar:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-camera:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-fire:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-lock:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-paperclip:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-pushpin:before {
  content: "";
}
.glyphicon-wrench:before {
  content: "";

.container-fluid .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Does anyone know what's causing the break up on to separate lines?

The page can be viewed here: http://www.test.ascentapps.com/indextest.html

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using bootstrap 3 which doesn't use `span4` anymore. You probably want something like `col-md-4`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Boy is my face red.. I had been working off a Bootstrap 3 tutorial so I wouldn't have thunk it'd be out of date… oh well.. Thank you very much! I knew it was something trivial :/

Comment: I just recently had to back-port a bootstrap 3 project to v2... so I had to deal with the class renames. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Will do. It's making me wait a few minutes.